# interface as Nullable

Tags: typescript, types, nullable

I've got the following types/interfaces:

```
type Nullable<T> = T | null;

export interface Employee {
  name: string;
  salary: number;
}
```

I don't want to define attributes of Employee to be Nullable, BUT the whole Employee should be Nullable.

Since I don't want do type everytime I use it as so `Nullable<Employee>`.
I'd rather just type it as `Employee` which then would automatically be `Employee | null`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need a type alias :

```
export type Employee = {
  name: string;
  salary: number;
} | null
```